# Cant get WiFi to work on Ostro (Yocto)

Tags: linux, wifi, yocto

I just built an Ostro os image and baked this onto a piece of hardware I have. However I am not able to get WiFi to work.

Here is the output of commands inorder to debug:

```
root@intel-corei7-64:~# uname -a
Linux intel-corei7-64 4.4.32-yocto-standard #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Jan 16 19:01:12 IST 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux

root@intel-corei7-64:~# ifconfig
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1%119/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1760 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1760 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:127360 (124.3 KiB)  TX bytes:127360 (124.3 KiB)

root@intel-corei7-64:~# lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Braswell SoC Transaction Router (rev 35)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Braswell Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 35)
00:03.0 Multimedia controller: Intel Corporation Braswell ISP Camera (rev 35)
00:0b.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Braswell P-Unit Power Management (rev 35)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Braswell USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 35)
00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Braswell Trusted Execution Engine Interface (rev 35)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Braswell PCIe Port 1 (rev 35)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Braswell PCIe Port 2 (rev 35)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Braswell Platform Controller Unit LPC (rev 35)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Braswell Platform Controller Unit SMBus (rev 35)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88W8897 [AVASTAR] 802.11ac Wireless
```

And when I run:

```
connmanctl enable wifi
Error wifi: Method "SetProperty" with signature "sv" on interface "net.connman.Technology" doesn't exist
```

What is missing here?

Answer (score 2):

According to https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/MWIFIEX.html, you have to have CONFIG_MWIFIEX in order to support the Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88W8897 [AVASTAR] 802.11ac Wireless.

Most probably you have to reconfigure your kernel to contain this.

EDIT: usually the default kernels provide the options to check their configuration like this (on the target machine)

```
zcat /proc/config.gz | grep "CONFIG_MWIFIEX"
```